# Rails not assigning unique ids to new records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

This morning I restored a database using [db:seed:dump](https://github.com/rroblak/seed_dump).  Now after trying to run a simple rake file, I'm getting the following error.

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "reports_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
: INSERT INTO "reports" ("worker_id", "report_month", "status", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"
/path/to/app/dir/lib/tasks/produce.rake:22:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/path/to/app/dir/lib/tasks/produce.rake:17:in `each'
/path/to/app/dir/lib/tasks/produce.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Caused by:
PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "reports_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
/path/to/app/dir/lib/tasks/produce.rake:22:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/path/to/app/dir/lib/tasks/produce.rake:17:in `each'
/path/to/app/dir/lib/tasks/produce.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => produce:report_month
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I've run this rake task dozens of times before without error, the only difference is that I've recently deployed a backup.

Reading the error it seems like Rails is trying to restart the ID interval back at 1, which is already occupied.

the seed:dump gem creates a seeds.rb file which has a structure like the following:

```
Note.create!([
  {id: 1, notable_id: 51, notable_type: "Worker", body: "Some sort of text here", created_at: "2017-10-27 00:27:21", updated_at: "2017-10-27 00:27:21"},
  {id: 2, notable_id: 68, notable_type: "Worker", body: "another note", created_at: "2017-11-11 18:43:13", updated_at: "2017-11-11 18:43:13"}
])
```

Has anyone encountered this before? any idea how to fix?

Comment: How did you deploy a backup? Looks like something inserted a bunch of data using SQL INSERTs but neglected to reset the sequences that supply `id` values. You can use [`setval`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html) to manually fix the sequences to take care of the current emergency.

Comment: the backup was deployed by running rake db:seed with the generated seeds.rb file provided by the db:seed:dump gem.  I've edited the question to include a typical section from the seeds.rb file.

Comment: Don't pass `id: 1` and `id: 2` so that the `id` will be autogenerated.

Comment: @AbM Then how would you maintain the relationships between the records?

Comment: `Note.create!` should put everything it needs into the database so you probably don't need to run any Rails code at all to restore the database so you might want to switch to `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` for this sort of thing. That might not mesh with the `db:seed` stuff as well but it will take care of sequences and FKs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: don't use the db:seed:dump gem for database backups.  At least not the way I was using it.

I ended up restoring from an earlier backup created via the pg_dump command.

Thank you to all of the commenters

Answer (score 0):

I imagine Notes.id is a serial. The seed is setting the id manually (id: 1, id:2, etc), so the sequence is not being used nor incremented. Now you should check the maximum id in the notes table and set the sequence to the next value.

```
ALTER SEQUENCE notes_id_seq RESTART WITH **VALUE** INCREMENT BY 1;
```